# MINGW64 curl set silent mode by default

Tags: curl, mingw

I am using curl (MINGW64 in windows) to test elasticsearch.
It always output like

```
$ curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    79  100    79    0     0   4937      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4937health status index pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
```

I have to type

```
$ curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v' --silent
health status index pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
```

How to make curl in silent mode by default.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found the magic when I search by keyword `ubuntu curl`.
It is very simple, just run

```
alias 'curl'='curl -s'
```

then `curl` in silent mode by default.